# why does this value get cut off?

Tags: hex, printf

So I'm trying to print out hex values in c++ using printf, and well, I want the output of the following string to be val:0x0366 including that leading 0

Here's the code

```
 int poo = 0x00000366;
 printf("val:0x%x \n",poo);
```

Here's the output:

```
0x366
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried  `printf("val:0x%04x \n",poo);`?

According to [printf reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf),

A format specifier follows this prototype:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

In your case:

```
%[0][4][default precision][default lenght]x
```

Comment: Just corrected it, you need to put the 0 flag so it prints 0's instead of spaces.